# Perserve HTML "Look" of Comments Inserted Into MYSQL Database From PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a website where users can post comments up to 280 characters in length. The probelm I'm having is that things like "\r\n" are showing up in the comments in the actual database and all apostrophes and quotation marks are preceeded by a "\". Why is this happening?

I'm using prepared statements to insert into the database.

How can I change this so exactly how the comment looks as it's typed is perserved as it's later loaded and read from the database (i.e. \r\n new lines, apostrophes, etc).

Here's how it's set up right now:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table SET comment=:comment");

$stmt->bindParam(':comment', $post, PDO::PARAM_STR, 280);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: browsers expect html, not text

Comment: Disable magic quotes.

Comment: It sounds like you have magic_quotes enabled. This has been deprecated since PHP 5.3.0 (circa June 2009). Here's how to disable it: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php
If you have a hosting service that can't or won't move away from deprecated features, get a difference hosting service.

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SET ...`??

Comment: Disable magic quotes or get rid of some sort of "sanitize" function, all PHP users are so inclined to.